# Apache Camel - Exception handling with multiple RouteBuilders

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am using **Apache Camel** to implement Rest APIs. I've 2 `RouteBuilder` types defining all the Camel routes, my application needs. All REST endpoints reside in `RestRouter`, and it frames the execution using `CustomRouter`. For example, I've `RestRouter` to hold my REST routes

```
public class RestRouter extends RouteBuilder
{
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception
    {
        rest("/sample")
                .post()
                .route()
                .routeId("postSample")
                .to("direct:validate")
                .to("direct:save")
                .endRest();
    }
}
```

And another RouteBuilder called `CustomRouter` to bundle non-REST routes.

```
public class CustomRouter extends RouteBuilder
{

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception
    {
        onException(ValidationException.class)
                .handled(true)
                .setBody(simple("${exchangeProperty[CamelExceptionCaught]}"))
                .to("bean:exceptionHandler?method=constraintViolationHandler")
                .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant(ErrorResponse.class.getName()))
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST));

        validator()
                .type(Sample.class)
                .withBean("sampleValidator");

        from("direct:validate")
                .to("bean-validator://x"); // Runs javax/Hibernate annotated validations

        from("direct:save")
                .routeId("saveSample")
                .inputTypeWithValidate(Sample.class)
                .to("bean:sampleRepository?method=save");
    }
}
```

Validation bean `SampleValidator` is a Camel `org.apache.camel.spi.Validator` which throws `org.apache.camel.ValidationException` for any violations.

Problem with setup is that **Camel doesn't invoke my custom exception handler for `ValidationException`.** Validation exception occurs for route **saveSample**. Here's my finding on how it goes further inside Camel processor types.

- Control goes to `RedeliveryErrorHandler's handleException()` where it looks for the exception policy. Root of failing exchange (i.e. `RestRouter` -> **postSample**) is expected here to define the exception handler.
- Later, Camel goes to failing `UnitOfWork` (i.e. to **saveSample**) to identify the exception handler.
- That means, for below expression, routeId is from **CustomRouter** and exceptionPolicy is from the **RestRouter**. Combination never exists and Camel fails to find the exception processor.

  `processor = exceptionPolicy.getErrorHandler(routeId)`

In above context, I've following questions

1. Is it a good practice to divide a functionality within multiple `RouterBuilder` types?
2. Shouldn't Camel use current `UnitOfWork` to resolve the exception policy?
3. Is there some way Camel can invoke my custom handler, provided different `RouteBuilder` types?

**Edit**
I can't move to have a single `RouterBuilder`.

- One, because I've an Apache Avro object coming in payload for post from another orchestration service, and then transformation to my JPA entities is done via the bean methods, not using Camel's `Transformer`. This arrangement doesn't fit with how Camel invokes the `Validator` (see`ContractAdvice`).  ContractAdvice is a `CamelInternalProcessorAdvice` which applies `Transformer` (if intype != outtype) and `Validator`.
- Second, moving to single `RouterBuilder` will need me to move Avro-to-Entity logic to a Camel `Transformer`, and that approach would differ greatly with the way we're doing currently. But yes, single RouterBuilder + Transformer + Validator should work.

Comment: I would generally keep one Builder and add all the details there

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this example from Camel In Action which demonstrates how to reuse  the error-handling across route builders defined in Java DSL.

[BaseRouteBuilder](https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2/blob/master/chapter11/reuse/src/test/java/camelinaction/BaseRouteBuilder.java) 
and  [InboxRouteBuilder](https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2/blob/master/chapter11/reuse/src/test/java/camelinaction/InboxRouteBuilder.java) and [OrderRouteBuilder](https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2/blob/master/chapter11/reuse/src/test/java/camelinaction/OrderRouteBuilder.java)

You can create a base class where you setup the context-scoped error configuration.Then your RouteBuilder classes are  extending this base class and calling calling super.configure to get the common configuration.

Comment: @Itsallas, I think doing so too won't work. `BaseRouteBuilder` approach will be equivalent to duplicating exception handlers. Check question for details on how it flows within RedeliveryErrorHandler processor.

Comment: @masT Hmm, I believe it will work. Inheritance is the official method proposed  in Camel Documentation http://camel.apache.org/error-handling-in-camel.html (see section scopes) to make context-scope which is implemented per route-builder in Java DSL global.

Comment: @Itsallas, tried the `BaseRouteBuilder` way, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

See if it works when you have all the routes in a single `RouteBuilder`.  "Global" exception handlers such as yours are not really global as they are applied to all routes built by that specific builder, so I wouldn't expect your `onException` to be applied to the REST route.

Alternatively move the `onException` in to the REST builder.  The handler sets HTTP status codes, so on the surface looks like it would be better packaged with REST routes.

Comment: Edited the question on why I can't have single RouterBuilder.